# Css reset at less than 320px

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I'm making a responsive design for every eventuality and what I'm trying to achieve is a media query that when the screen width is less than 320 , remove all of my styling/javascript/images and simply give the `<h1> <h6>` and `<p>` as plain black text with a white background?

Is this something that can be done?

Here's what I have so far:
CSS:

```
div.alert{
  height:100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#f3fb9c;
  color: #000000;
  display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 319px) {    
  .alert {display:inline;}
}
```

HTML div

```
<div class="alert">Because you are viewing this page on a decive with a very small screen this page has been set to only show basic content.</div>
```

Comment: You're going to be making a lot of work for yourself trying to remove styles this way. It would be much simpler to *start* with no styles and **add** them as the screen size increases. Good luck.

Comment: I don't get this.  Markup without styling is already doing what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use media queries. Add your `basic styling` on top. Next add a simple media query with all your fancy colors.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    color: black;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
        color: red;
    }
}
```